What was the JETkey "Fastest keyboard BIOS" keyboard controller?
Perusing old PC mainboards, I sometimes see "JETkey" brand keyboard controllers, which sport the JETkey logo, a version number (usually 5.0) and the proud claim: "Fastest keyboard BIOS" – but no manufacturer name (unless the manufacturer was simply "JETkey").
Information on this chip is difficult to find on the Internet. From this terse website, I gather that: at least two versions exist, v3.0 and v5.0, both from 1992; they were manufactured by Samsung (which doesn't necessarily mean they were designed and sold by Samsung as well), and they were not 8042 clones or even microcontrollers at all.
What I don't understand is why speed would have been an important quality in a keyboard controller. This was not the era of "professional gamers" worrying about every nanosecond that might give them an advantage, and even if somebody was worried about that, the processing inside the keyboard controller should have been the least of his worries – the transmission of scancodes from the keyboard to the PCs was probably slower by an order of magnitude. (This interesting discussion of PS/2 keyboard speed gives a whole millisecond for the keyboard to send a single byte. The 8042 keyboard controller runs at 6 MHz minimum.)
So I'm wondering: Who made these chips, and what was their appeal/marketing pitch? Did people buy these to replace the existing 8042s in their PCs so they could enter numbers in Excel quicker?

If 'fast' is the only differentiator you've got, fast is what you will advertise.

What exactly is the "keyboard BIOS"? Is it the code executed by the keyboard controller chip, or the keyboard portion of the BIOS code that runs on the main CPU?

Input could often seem slow. But it wasn't the keyboard slowing it down but everything else happening on a slow computer.

@NateEldredge in this context, "keyboard BIOS" refers to the keyboard controller chip and its firmware (if it has any).

Adrian's Digital Basement (youtube channel) has a video on under/overclocking a 286 motherboard and found that performance of different keyboard controllers mattered when running at different frequencies. Might be related?

@bjb I watched a video from Adrian on running his 286 at 1 MHz. Funnily, he ended up using a JETkey – the "fastest keyboard BIOS" was the only one that could go that slow. The 8042 is out of spec below ~1.6 MHz, but that is only part of the problem. I believe that if you run it considerably below 6 MHz, it works in principle but is too slow to sample the keyboard signal. This is probably why the JETkey can be clocked slower than a normal 8042 and still work!

(My theory is based on my experience with a NEC µPD80C42 keyboard controller, which has a nominal clock range from 1 to 12 MHz, and which works perfectly at 6 MHz, but doesn not seem to return proper scan codes at 4 MHz.)

The keyboard controller in the IBM AT is (as its name implies) used to interface the keyboard, but that's not its only purpose. As soon as you have a microcontroller on the board, you can assign other duties besides keyboard interfacing to it. It turns out that IBM needed to control two logic lines on the mainboard: IBM required a way to have the processor receive a reset pulse and a way to mask A20 for PC/XT compatible address sapce wrap around.
Protected mode software and XMS drivers (as well as DOS running in the HMA) required the non-PC/XT-compatible mode with A20 unmasked. On the other hand, it initially wasn't know how much software requires A20 to be mask to work correctly. Also, every time a protected mode program (like Windows 3.x in standard mode) wanted to issue a DOS or BIOS call, it had to reset the CPU to get to real mode. This is a complicated process, which involved telling the keyboard controller to generate a reset pulse, and then having the BIOS read a byte from CMOS that instructs the BIOS to jump to some address given in the BIOS data area. The latency in processing the "please reset the CPU" command caused by the keyboard controller may not be the most significant part in this process, but it definitely contributed a measureable amount of time to it.
IBM themselves provided discrete logic in the later PS/2 series that was intended to replace the AT and AT clones, which got commonly known as "fast A20 gate" which IIRC also included a reset mechanism.
Both the time to enable/disable A20 and the time to switch back from protected mode to real mode were targets of microbenchmarks by DOS extenders back in the day, and could be improved by having keyboard controller chip that responds faster to those commands.

Interestingly, the A20 gate seems to have been such a sensitive issue that Intel built a so-called Hardware A20 Gate Support into the later CHMOS version of its 8042 (the 80C42 and 80L42 chips, the latter being 3.3V versions), which bypasses the normal programmed command processing. (Must be activated via a special opcode first.)
